# getRenditions() on org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.CmisObject returns null

Tags: java, apache, cmis, apache-chemistry

I am using Apache Chemistry 0.14.0 to access documents in Alfresco 5.1. I am using AtomPub binding to access Alfresco.

When I invoke getRenditions() method on CmisDocument null is returned for all documents. Any ideas what could be the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, renditions are not requested. You have to use an OperationContext with a rendition filter.

See:

- https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/content/index.html#working-with-renditions
- https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/operation-context/index.html#rendition-filter